# Replace N occurrences of string with two in a select

Tags: mysql, replace

I am trying to clean up `<br>` in files I get down to two max.

I can of course nest Replaces:

`Replace(Replace(Field,'<br><br><br>','<br><br>'),'<br><br><br>','<br><br>')`

But it is slow and unwieldy and eventually I'll get caught by a record with one extra `<br>`. Is there anyway to do this with some sort of 'N' meaning 'replace any string with more than two `<br>`s in a row with two `<br>`s?

Comment: You might look into using RegEx. That would be able to specify a min-max number in the search part.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are doing it twice, but `replace(field_name, '<br><br><br>', '<br><br>')` should do!

Comment: @SloanThrasher Good Call: 1(<br>){3,10}=><br><br>1

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer Not it replaces 3 occurrences of `<br>` with two but if say I have 4 occurrences it simply changes it to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.  Also, only updates rows that have more than 3 adjacent `<br>`.

```
update my_table
  set field = regexp_replace (field, '(<br>){3,}', '<br><br>')
  where field regexp '(<br>){3,}';
```

The `(<br>)` matches a single `<br>`.  The `{3,}` matches 3 or more `<br>`.